# Read and store contents of large ASCII file

Tags: java, ascii, large-files

I got a 538MB ASCII file with 16807 lines and each line has 16807 0s and 1s separated by space. I want to take all these values and store them in a list of lists, as to store every line in a new list.

In a previous project I made the below code for a text file but with the ASCII file it throws me an Java heap space error.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOflists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\Users...\file.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    while (true)
    {
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }

        Scanner tokenize = new Scanner(line);
        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (tokenize.hasNext()) 
        {
            tokens.add(tokenize.next());
        }
        listOflists.add(tokens);
    }
    br.close();
```

Now I made this code but again throws me Java heap space error.

```
String inputFile = "C:\Users...\file.txt";

    LinkedList<LinkedList<Character>> charList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Character>>();

    File file = new File( inputFile );
    Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
    char val = 0;
    int c;
    int iLine = 0;

    while( (c = reader.read()) != -1) {

        val = (char)c;
        charList.add(new LinkedList<Character>());

        if((c == 48) || (c == 49)){ //ascii code for 0 is 48 and for 1 is 49
            charList.get(iLine).add(val);
        }
        if( c == 92 ){ //ascii code for "/" is 92 as to know when it changes line
            iLine++;
     } 
}
reader.close();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Increase the heap memory, or store it in a less memory consuming way.

Comment: I increase the heap memory with this, -Xmx1024m, but the error stays and the purpose of the question is to find a less memory consuming way, cause i couldnt find any.

Comment: Whats the point in doing this ? Read the file and store it in a bitfield, this will decrease the memory usage considerably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know exactly where was the error in my previous code but here is a solution where i read the file and store the position of 1s in a list (first the column and then the row in which i found it).
As to help more, i also change the VM Option of the project and add -Xmx1g as to increase the heap size. Without this i get an OutOfMemory error(running the code in 3G RAM system)

```
    String inputFile = "C:\Users\...\file.txt";
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    FileChannel ch = in.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int column=-1;
    int row=0;
    int rd;
    while ((rd = ch.read( buf )) != -1){
        buf.flip();
        while (buf.hasRemaining()){
            byte byteVal = buf.get();

            if((byteVal == 48) || (byteVal == 49)){ //ascii code for 0 is 48 and for 1 is 49
                column++;
            }
            if (byteVal == 92){ //ascii code for "/" is 92 as to know when it changes line
                    row++;
                    column=0;
            }
            if(byteVal == 49){
                list.add(column);
                list.add(row);

            }
        }
    buf.clear();
    }
    ch.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty list

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Character>> charList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Character>>();
```

and you are trying to get the first element

```
charList.get(iLine)
```

from an empty list so the IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Comment: I just show that i have posted the wrong code, I edit my question and post the correct one that throws me IndexOutOfBounds Exception but Java heap space error. But your comment was correct for the previous code.

Comment: Increase heap size. For example this parameter -Xmx1024m will give you 1024MB of Java heap space.

Comment: I did that but again the same problem, Java heap space.

Comment: You read whole file into your memory. Try to read it more efficiently. Check this link http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file or you can try to give a bigger value to your heap size like -Xmx4g (4GB) - I don't know your RAM amount.

Comment: I got 3GB RAM, but even with -Xmx1g the out of memory error remains, with bigger heap size the VM has problem to initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a new `LinkedList` for every iteration of your while loop with the line `charList.add(new LinkedList<Character>());`, even if the line doesn't change.

Comment: yes but without this i get an IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Comment: So instead of fixing that bug, you decided that you'll add so many `lists` that instead of getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you'll run out of memory? You only need to add a list for each line, and of course before the loop add the list for the first line.

Comment: I try to store all the values of the file to a single list, despite the fact that it is not what i want to do, but the java heap space remaines. So i think the problem is not the lists.

Comment: Well the lists are your main problem. The minor part is that your code is  wrong, the major part is that you're trying to load characters into a list of lists, which is an extremely bad choice. You never said what you're trying to do with a list of lists of characters, but I'd bet you dollars to donuts that there's a better data structure for what you're trying to do.

Comment: The file is like an array 16807x16807 with 0s and 1s as elements and i want to store it somewhere as to know in which column and row i got 1s and in which 0s. If you got another idea where to store the data as the code to be functional with different files of this format please let me know.

Comment: Well since you're reading essentially bits, why not store them as bits too. You could fit 64 of them in a single long.